# How to detect quad buffered stereo capability on Mac?

Tags: macos, opengl, stereo-3d

I want my application to correctly detect the presence of a quad buffered video card, so I can enable stereo viewing, only when 3D viewing is possible.

I have two Mac computers here: 1) Mac Pro Mac OS 10.6.8 desktop with nvidia Quadro 4000 video card ; 2) MacBook Pro laptop Mac OS 10.6.8 with two video boards a: built in Intel HD graphics and b: nvidia GeForce 330M.

The first computer has a connector for 3D glasses on the card.  That's the one I want to display stereo 3D on.  I don't think it's possible to view hardware stereo on the second laptop computer.  So I want my application to detect which sort of computer it is on, and react appropriately.  I thought I knew how to do that.  But it isn't working.  My application thinks quad buffered stereo works on both computers.

Witness a simple test program:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

"""
Test program to demonstrate apparent quad-
buffered stereo support on Mac laptop
"""

from OpenGL.GL import *
from PySide.QtGui import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PySide.QtOpenGL import QGLWidget, QGLFormat
import sys

class MyGLWidget(QGLWidget):
    "Simple OpenGL canvas to test stereoscopic display capabilities"
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        # Constructor for QGLWidget grabs a default OpenGL context
        # (which was set up in the main program, below)
        QGLWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        if self.format().stereo():
            # According to Qt docs, this is supposed to be the way to detect
            # quad buffered stereo support
            print "Quad buffered stereo appears to work(2)"
        self.useStereo = self.format().stereo()

    def initializeGL(self):
        "initializeGL is called once, after the OpenGL context is really ready"
        print "initializeGL"
        if glGetBooleanv(GL_STEREO):
            # This is the real OpenGL way to detect quad buffered stereo
            print "Quad buffered stereo appears to work(3)"
        self.useStereo = glGetBooleanv(GL_STEREO)

    def paintGL(self):
        if self.useStereo:
            # Left eye fill with yellow
            glDrawBuffer(GL_BACK_LEFT)
            glClearColor(1, 1, 0, 1)
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
            # Right eye fill with cyan
            glDrawBuffer(GL_BACK_RIGHT)
            glClearColor(0, 1, 1, 1)
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
        else:
            # Both eyes fill with green
            glDrawBuffer(GL_BACK) # both left and right
            glClearColor(0, 1, 0, 1)
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)

# Attempt to use stereoscopic QGLFormat OpenGL format
# To work, this must be called before MyGLWidget is constructed.
fmt = QGLFormat.defaultFormat()
fmt.setStereo(True)
if fmt.stereo():
    print "Quad buffered stereo appears to work(1)"
QGLFormat.setDefaultFormat(fmt)

# The usual Qt hello world boilerplate...
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = QMainWindow()
win.setCentralWidget(MyGLWidget(win))
win.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

On both computers, all three "Quad buffered stereo appears to work" messages are printed.
On the stereo-ready workstation with a 120Hz stereo monitor, the background of the window appears pale lime green, as it switches between the yellow and cyan colors at 120 Hz.  On a 60Hz monitor, it is possible to perceive the seizure-inducing flickering between the two colors.   This flickering also appears on the laptop, suggesting that maybe it really does support quad buffered stereo?

One final wrinkle:  If I connect the laptop to an external monitor, I see the flickery superposition on the external monitor, but on the laptop screen the window is yellow, i.e. the BACK_LEFT buffer color only.  With just the laptop screen or just the external monitor, I observe the flickery phenotype.

Does the GeForce 330M video board really support quad buffered stereo on Mac?
Is there a better way to detect a real quadro board from my program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Mac computers I have tested support quad buffered stereo.  Even those with so-called consumer level (i.e. non-Quadro) video cards.  This explains why even my laptop claims to support stereo.  Because it does.

To prove that all Macs support quad buffered stereo, I needed 3D hardware that accepts frame sequential stereo without a sync signal.  I now have that at my work.  And I am viewing beautiful quad-buffered stereo from Mac computers.  This is awesome.  So why am I unable to find any vendor who sells Mac oriented stereo3D solutions?  This beautiful capability is sitting latent on Macs, and nobody seems to realize it is there.

Comment: Could you give more details about your hardware solution?

Comment: @JWWalker We use a Christie 3D projector at work.  These projectors accept a frame doubled stereo mode.  But they are probably beyond the consumer price range.  http://www.christiedigital.com/en-us/3d/products-and-solutions/projectors/pages/default.aspx

Comment: Yeah, they don't even list prices on their web site, so it's probably way out of my range.  But thanks.